# why the list can't append a number?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

```
>>> x=list(range(1,9))
>>> x.append(9)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y=list(range(1,9)).append(9)
>>> print(y)
None
```

Why x can append a number ,the list(range(1,9)) can not append a same number in my python3?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the behaviour. `append` *does* add the number to the list.

The problem is, the `append` method doesn't return anything (= `None`). You expected the return value to be the list itself.

Just use the first approach.